# Why robots.txt file is supposed to block sub folder but blocking some random files also

Tags: blocking, robots.txt

I was getting some strange URLs indexed for my site by adding files as folders. One sample URL is here

`https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-scale.php/math.php`

I have a file `tkinter-scale.php` but don’t have a directory in that name

Similarly this URL is also indexed, you can ses file names are included as folder names.

`https://www.plus2net.com/python/tkinter-sqlite.php/javascript_tutorial/asp-tutorial/site_map.php`

Then I added these two lines to `robots.txt` file remove all the subfolders after `/python/`, so I can index the files inside python folder but not down the level.

```
Allow: /python/$
Disallow: /python/
```

Now I have a big list of files blocked by `robots.txt` file, which is correct and they are inside sub – folders of python directory. But there are five files which are also blocked ( out of a list of nearly 500 ).

```
https://www.plus2net.com/python/string-rjust.php
https://www.plus2net.com/python/dj-mysql-add-data.php
https://www.plus2net.com/python/next.php
https://www.plus2net.com/python/test.csv
https://www.plus2net.com/python/string-islower.php
```

Why these files are blocked?
( there is no page level blocking for these files )

Answer (score 0):

Your current `robots.txt` `Allow` rule is not allowing anything within the `python` directory. Neither files, nor sub-directories, just the base directory itself. It looks to me like you want your `robots.txt` to look like:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: *.php/
```

OR

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /python/
Allow: /python/$
Allow: /python/*.php$
```

These two would be pretty equivalent for the major search engines. They process `Allow` directives, `*` as wildcard and `$` as "ends with". These rules would differ for most other crawlers that don't know about Google's `robots.txt` syntax extensions. The first set of rules would allow them to crawl everything, the second set of rules would block the entire `python` directory.

For future reference, I would suggest testing your `robots.txt` against [Google's `robots.txt` testing tool](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/07/testing-robotstxt-files-made-easier).

---

Another way of solving this problem is to configure your web server not to allow paths after file names.  If you are using Apache, you could set the following in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`.

`AcceptPathInfo Off`